# aframe-video-controls: how to adjust the width and length of video player in PC

Tags: aframe

Every time I use aframe-video-controls for video. A full web browser video are shown.  I want to show the video with specified length or width. And I also want to put it in specified position like in html. How can I do it?

https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position` component to position and `scale` component to scale.

```
  <!-- 360 video, rotated 180-degrees to select an initial view. -->
  <a-videosphere src="#cityVideo" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>

  <!-- Video controls. -->
  <a-entity
    video-controls="src: #cityVideo; backgroundColor: #333; barColor: #EF2D5E; textColor: #DADADA; infoTextTop: Gaze and click on the icon or progress bar.; infoTextBottom: Double-click outside of the player to toggle it."
    position="0 1 -2" scale="1 1.5 1"></a-entity>
```

https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/position.html
https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/scale.html

Comment: Thanks very much. Maybe I didn't describe this question clearly. My question is that when I use such codes, the video will be full of all the screen. I don't want it. For example, I need the video to occupy the half of the screen(browser). And the video is at the specified position(like in html, the left , top ,bottom or right attributes) . And how can I realize this  feature?

Comment: You can create a semi-sphere `<a-sphere theta-length="180" phi-length="180">` https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/geometry.html#sphere

Comment: I created a question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857027/how-to-create-a-180-degree-semisphere-segment-partial-video-sphere-in-a-frame/38857090#38857090