# How to create a 180-degree/semisphere/segment/partial video sphere in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

`<a-videosphere src="myvideo.mp4">` displays a video on an entire 360-degree sphere, but I want to display a video or image, but only on a portion of a sphere like a hemisphere. Something like:

[image]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/SphericalSegment_1000.gif))</sub>

How would I do this in A-Frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sphere geometry (`<a-entity geometry="primitive: sphere">` or `<a-sphere>`) and control the `phiLength/thetaLength` angles of the sphere to specify a segment. Theta length controls horizontal sweep angle and phi length controls vertical sweep angle:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mediabox.fr](http://forums.mediabox.fr/wiki/_media/tutoriaux/flashplatform/affichage/3d/carrousel_papervision/sphere/theta_phi.png))</sub>

For a hemisphere, we would do:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: sphere; thetaLength: 180; radius: 5000; segmentsWidth: 64; segmentsHeight: 20" scale="1 1 -1" material="src: #myVideo; shader: flat"></a-entity>
```

Or:

```
<a-sphere theta-length="180">
```

And then apply the material.

**For videosphere, we can update it:**

```
<a-videosphere src="#myVideo" geometry="thetaLength: 180"></a-videosphere>
```

However, the video won't be cropped as you'd expect. So you might have to crop beforehand. If you want it to crop like `background-size: cover`, we might have to do something special like hide portions of the sphere.

Comment: Tried today and found thetaLength should be 90 instead of 180 to create a semisphere in terms of latitude.